# os.makedirs access denied, Windows not prompting for admin perms

Tags: python, directory

I am creating an installer for an app. I need it to create a directory in ProgramFiles(x86) and then add content to that file.

```
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join((os.environ["ProgramFiles(x86)"]),"testApp")):
            pass
        else:
            os.makedirs(os.path.join((os.environ["ProgramFiles(x86)"]),"testApp"))
```

This returns:
 `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\testAPP`

Most installers open a windows admin prompt when using them, but I'm not sure how to force that prompt and give the installer the permissions it needs to complete the task.

I have tried using mkdir() instead, but I get the same result.
I have also attempted to have the app run as administrator, and in doing that, I got the Windows admin prompt to appear when launching the installer, but the function still gets denied.